# How to play alloy ui video continuously/repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, alloy-ui

I want to play alloy ui video to be repeated once it finish, below is my the code any help will be appreciated

```
<div id="myVideo"></div>
<script>
AUI().use(
'aui-video',
function(A) {
var video = new A.Video(
    {
        boundingBox: '#myVideo',
        fixedAttributes: {
        allowfullscreen: 'true'
    },
    ogvUrl: 'http://videos.liferay.com/lifecasts/portal/6.0/106.ogv',
    swfUrl: 'http://videos.liferay.com/common/player.swf',
    poster: '/documents/10184/22494/home1.jpg',
    url: '/documents/10184/21495/ACC+Drive+7-28_h264_2.mp4',
    }
).render();
video.play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your actual `video` element is wrapped inside that `div` with id `myVideo`. All you need to do is get that `video` element and add a listener to it. Mozilla has a really good [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) on Media events and the one you are looking for is

> **ended** : Sent when playback completes.

So, you need to find the `video` element inside that `div` may be using a [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or any other library function if you are using JQuery.

Once you have the `video` element, just add a listener to it. (Assuming `videoElement` is the DOM node you found.

```
videoElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
   //Replay your video here
}, true);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `loop` element to your HTML code as `loop="true"` or `loop="loop"`. 
If you want to do it in JQuery, you can write the code as
`$(".myVideo").attr('loop','loop');`